# Make the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ reset itself when read from a different tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange-button, live-refresh

Since recently, the StackExchange button asynchronously updates itself (meaning it shows new notifications without needing to reload the page). This is all nice and dandy, however I usually have multiple tabs open and the notification doesn't get reset when I click on the button in any one tab.

This is a bit disruptive, as that little red dot in the corner naturally catches my attention. Can has asynchronous reset?

Comment: If it can set itself, it can unset itself. Good point.

Comment: ["How Do You Get A Unicorn's Attention?'](http://gerbsrandomthoughts.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-do-you-get-unicorns-attention.html)

Comment: +1 This has been bothering me as well. :(

Comment: I just tried this, and it works now (checking the notification cleared them in all my tabs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were some rough edges around clearing the inbox count on other tabs.  This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: Tested and confirmed working, arigatou. :)