# Supercollider realtime updates incomplete-ish

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, live-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ reset itself when read from a different tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125460/make-the-stackexchange-multicollider-superdropdown-reset-itself-when-read-from)

Alright, we have a nifty new feature for our Supercollider. It runs realtime updates and glows red automatically.

Well, I keep lots of tabs open, so all the tabs get the glowing red thingy. Fine with me.

But, if I read the inbox message from one tab, the glow is still visible in the others. And it doesn't seem to realtime update itself out of the way.  Which means that I expectantly end up clicking the supercollider every time I switch tabs. I'm sure the bug is partially inside me, but I'd just like to bring it to the notice of the devs.

[image]

Comment: Obviously, refreshing the screen will clear the supercollider notification if there aren't any unnoticed messages. It's become habit for me now so you can't suddenly make it work _logically_.

Comment: @M.Babcock: What's the point of realtime updates if you still have to refresh? I'm new enough to the network to still have a working <kbd>F5</kbd> key, and I like it that way ;)

Comment: Well that's not fair... mine died a couple months ago. What makes you so special?

Comment: @Manishearth I did add a feature that would clear the inbox notification on all browser tabs when the inbox is clicked.  I'll check for any lingering bugs here since you're reporting it isn't working.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas - Based on what I've seen, it definitely isn't working correctly if it was "fixed". I see this problem at least a couple times a day.

Comment: @Geoff also, in the past few days, the  SEMCSD™ has been eating up some notifications. I never got pinged for the third and fourth entries in the above screenshot. Happene d yesterday as well.. It seems to happen when I open SE after half a day's absence (ie sleep)

Comment: Or should that be a separate bugreport? I can't repro it at will, unfortunately.

Comment: @Manishearth I will keep a close eye on the inbox tomorrow - until then I will leave this post open