# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDrowdown™ doesn't reset notifications when opened from multiple tabs

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button

So, we got the [self-reset when open in multiple tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125460/156727), however it seems there is a bug for the notifications part. I opened the StackExchange button in multiple tabs, clicked on the notification part in one, and still had the little `(1)` in the corner on the other tabs.

Can has bugfix?